# The normal and bernoulli distributions

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator, rao-blackwell

I'm working on this problem and am a little stumped. I was wondering if someone could give me a hint?

$x_1,...,x_n$ are iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu$ is unknown and $\sigma$ is known. $n>3$

let $\tau(\mu)=P_{\mu}(X_1+X_2\leq a)$ where a is some known real number. Find an initial unbiased estimator $T$ for  $\tau(\mu)$ and then derive the Rao-Blackwellized version

---

I started with $P_{\mu}(X_1+X_2\leq a)=P_{\mu}(X_i+X_j\leq a)=E[I(X_i+X_j\leq a)]=E[I(X_i\leq a-X_j)]=E[I(X_i\leq a-x_j|X_j=x_j)]$
but then i get lost.

Is this my unbiased estimator? and if it is how do i R-B it?

Comment: What is the distribution of sum of two independent normal random variables?

Comment: The simplest unbiased estimator of a probability is an indicator random variable for the same event, so define $I = 1$ if $X_1 + X_2 \leq a$ and $I = 0$ if $X_1 + X_2 > a$.  Note also that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is sufficient for $\mu$ and hence sufficient for $\tau(\mu)$ so the estimator you're seeking is $\text{E}(I \mid \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)$.